# Flex: replace all spaces with comma

Tags: regex, apache-flex

im new with regexp, so can i ask for some assistance

Using string.replace function what code that can replace spaces with comma

Input:The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
Output:The,quick,brown,fox,jumps,over,the,lazy dog.

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Like this:

```
str = str.replace(/ /g, ',');
```

Here's a better one which will replace all strings of whitespace:

```
str = str.replace(/\s+/g, ',');
```