# PartialMatchFilter issue

Tags: php, silverstripe

There is a search page on the site, so site visitors can search stuff either by city or/and by name. So the city is a drop down filter and the name search is a PartialMatchFilter text field.

The PartialMatchFilter works fine with one part of name being searched eg Tim or Smith, then Tim Glen Smith shows up. The issue I'm having is when you seach Tim Smith, it says no match because I missed Glen in the middle.

Can PartialMatchFilter work for this case when people don't know the middle name of the person? How is the best way to do it? Thanks.

Below is the code.

```
$filters = array (
'YourName' => new PartialMatchFilter("YourName"),
'YourCity' => new ExactMatchMultiFilter("YourCity"),
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PartialMatchFilter is the equivalent of

```
WHERE FieldName LIKE '%{$your_input}%'
```

so will only ever match the exact string somewhere in the field.

In order to be able to search for multiple words within the field, you'd be better off using [FullTextFilter](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-FulltextFilter.html).

Comment: Hi Irogue, thanks for your reply. I'd like to make the name searchable by any part of name a visitor would know, eg search for Tim, Smith, Tim Smith, or even just T, Tim Glen Smith would show up. Would the FulltextFilter work? Not sure replace PartialMatchFilter with FulltextFilter would work? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Irogue, thanks for your reply. I tried to replace $filters = array ('YourName' => new PartialMatchFilter("YourName"),..} with $filters = array ('YourName' => new FulltextFilter("YourName"),..} but it threw me an error - [User Error] Couldn't run query: SELECT DISTINCT "Profile"...Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list. Anything I am doing wrong? I am using SS2.4.5. Any suggestions would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Have a look at the link to the FulltextFilter in my original answer - it explains right at the top how to add the indexes.

Comment: Thanks Irogue, not sure why it didn't work before, possible some cache issue, it is all working now with your suggestion. Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to replace the whitespace in your search criteria with a percent sign

eg "Tim Smith" becomes "Tim%Smith"

Then the partial match filter should be able to find the right records.

Comment: Hi PB, you are right if you put "Tim%Smith" Tim Glem Smith does come up, however a visitor comes to my site to look for Tim wouldn't know to put the % sign inbetween the names. Is there any way to write this into the php code so that a random visitor types in Tim Glen, it will automatically change it to Tim%Smith to make this partial match filter work? Thanks.

Comment: Personally, my approach would be to use a regexp and preg_replace to replace any consecutive whitespace with a single %.  

Given my low familiarity with regexp it would take me ages to find the most appropriate expression to use, however. I'm sure there are other members who would be able to help with that.

Sequeing off this question "[replace all spaces with comma](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504863/flex-replace-all-spaces-with-comma)" you could use something like:

`
str = preg_replace("/\s+/g", '%', $searchCriteria);
`

Comment: Make that code-snippet `$searchCriteria = preg_replace("/\s+/g", '%', $searchCriteria);`

Comment: Thank you PB, I have been trying with your code but unsuccessful so far, I added more code above, would you be able to point me to the right direction on how to implement your suggestion to my code? Thank you.

Comment: Try replacing `'Value' => $data['YourName']` with `'Value' => preg_replace("/\s+/", "%", $data['YourName'])`

Comment: You may find this page useful for testing regular expressions used in preg_replace: [PHP Online Function Tester](http://php.fnlist.com/regexp/preg_replace)

Comment: Thanks P, I tried your code and I like your logic for this case but the search result says 'Name:Tim%Smith, sorry can't find any matching result.' Like mentioned before, when I put 'Tim%Smith' in, Tim Glen Smith does come up, but visitors wouldn't know to put % in. Any other suggestions please? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks PapaBearNZ, I used FulltextFilter instead, I'm still interested in how preg_replace would work for this case tho. Thanks for your help.