# how to remove spaces in between string in java,without using library function?

Tags: java, string, logic, spaces, replaceall

I am getting the solution is as follows

```
class StringCheck
{
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {   
        String str="Hello world I am here";
        String r;

        System.out.println(str);    
        r = str.replaceAll(" ","");
        System.out.println(r);  
    }
}
OUTPUT: HelloworldIamhere
```

but I don't want to use a library function i.e str.replaceAll(), Can anyone help me with the program.I want same output as I got using library function

Comment: As a human, how would you do it? Ask yourself what the algorithm is?

Comment: Why do you not want to use a library function?  Why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26931946/7316675

Comment: Possible solution :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504863/flex-replace-all-spaces-with-comma

Answer (score 1):

What I understood from your question is you don't want to use `str.replaceAll()` function. So possible alternative is following. Please refer more details [Removing whitespace from strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5455794/3213745)

```
import java.util.*;

public class StringCheck {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Hello world I am here";
        String r = "";

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(str);

        while(sc.hasNext()) {
            r += sc.next();
        }
        System.out.println(r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well as you do not want to keep the value just loop and print

```
    String str="Hello world I am here";

    for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
        if (c != ' ')
            System.out.print(c);
    }
```

**output**

HelloworldIamhere

Of course if you wanted to keep this new String then use a StringBuilder and `append` the char instead of/and print it

Answer (score 0):

## Iterate each char in `str`.

If it is not equal ' ', append it to your result string `r`.

But why would you want to do it without using library functions?

Comment: How does this answer add anything that's not already provided with the other answers?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Removespaces {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     String s = sc.nextLine();
     char[] ch = s.toCharArray();
     String s1 = "";
     for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i++){
         if(s.charAt(i)==' ')
         {
                 continue;
         }else{
             s1 = s1 + s.charAt(i);
         }
     }
     System.out.println(s1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have solution for that question you can have this way. I didn’t use in-build function

public class RemoveSpace {

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str="Abd is a good guy";
    
    char[] a=str.toCharArray();
    System.out.println(a);
    int size=a.length;
    for(int i=0; i<size;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==32)
        {
            for(int j=i;j<size-1;j++)
            {
                a[j]=a[j+1];
            }
            size--;
            
        }
        
    }
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
    System.out.print(a[i]);
    }
}}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
String s = "Hello world I am here";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
    if (c != ' ') {
        sb.append(c);
    }
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```